# Mathematical notation for a variable greater than two variables.

Tags: notation

I want to write $x$ is greater than $a$ or $b$, which ever is greater of the two. Should I write it like $x>\max(a,b)$.

Thank you.

Comment: `$x>\max\{a,b\}$` $x>\max\{a,b\}$.

Comment: But it is not correct. Since $a$ *or* $b$, perhaps it should be $x>\min\{a,b\}$.

Comment: It sounds like you want to say $x$ is greater than both $a$ and $b$. if that is the case then you are correct.

Comment: It is fine to just say $x>a \text{ and } x>b$ or combine that as you did using a max as $x>\max\{a,b\}$. Note that mathematicians tend to think of $\max$ as a function that works on a set, hence the curly brackets.